# How would a belt sander wing perform?

Tags: aerodynamics, wing

This is a theoretical question, the belt sander is an analogy to help visualize.
How would a rectangular wing that is able to make its outer skin circulate around the airfoil perimeter perform?

Feasibility issues aside, would this contraption help delaying airflow separation at high AoA ?

[image]

Comment: One prototype of the yov-10a bronco had a rotating-cylinder-flap concept. It enabled a flap deflection to up to 80°, thereby postponning stall. The problem was, that a real wing is bending and therefore the rotating part of this flap has to be designed according to the experienced bending, which was a challenge. Found a report about the concept here: https://blackpony.org/v4-yov10a881nasarep.pdf

Comment: Related? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBq-gNkBZWw Also-- ultra-simple demonstration of rotating cylinder creating lift-- hold sytrafoam drink cup horizontally, open palm of one hand on top, open palm of other hand on bottom, give it a hard spin as you throw it, if spin direction is such that top surface is moving *away* from direction of  travel (the more natural way to throw it), cup "flies" a long way, if spin direction is such that top surface is moving *toward* direction of travel, flight path curves sharply earthward and cup quickly hits ground--

Comment: I find the belt sander hilarious in an aviation.se post. Look at it chillin'!

Comment: "now with included de-icing system"

Comment: Related : [Flettner Rotor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flettner_rotor) - related to the [Magnus Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect)

Comment: You'd want to increase lift by *circulating the belt in the opposite direction*. As it is, air speed is reduced on the upside and increased on the downside - increasing pressure above and decreasing pressure below the "wing". This works in the opposite direction of desired lift.

Comment: @Zac67 No, you've got it backwards, and for the wrong reasons.  Read the Magnus Effect link above.

Comment: @J... The Magnus effect doesn't really apply: it requires the leading and the trailing edges to be exposed to actually redirect the air stream. With flaps like in the diagram, the Bernouilli effect outweighs Magnus and that demands a reversal of the rotation.

Comment: @Zac67 I don't see how that makes sense.  I think you need to post an answer with some mathematics.

Answer (score 29):

**RE** "Feasibility issues aside, would this contraption help delaying airflow separation at high AoA?":

According to a team that tested it, yes:

> The major advantages of a Magnus effect device are high-lift
> forces or rather high wing-loading and stall resistance [...]

Their design housed the *treadmill* in such a way that only the upper moving surface is exposed. According to their tables, they tested only up to 5° AOA. They acknowledge the complexity and added weight—and I'll add to that, reduced thrust and fuel capacity to power and house the system, respectively.

> [image]

Side note: if the goal is not a novel STOL RC plane, one popular and tested method for high AOA is [leading-edge root extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Leading-edge_extension&oldid=1055386900#Leading-edge_root_extension) (LERX).

---

- Patkunam, Kavithasan, et al. "[Experimental study of magnus effect over an aircraft wing](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?&q=%22Experimental%20study%20of%20magnus%20effect%20over%20an%20aircraft%20wing%22)." *International Journal of Research in Engineering and Technology* 4.10 (2015): 406-415.

Comment: This is a great find, even if I don't get why they only test a small portion on the upperwing in the first place. Maybe it's the result of previous testings.